# how to get updated images from web?

Tags: android, imageview, web-storage

I'm building an app that is pulling images from the web to display in an imageView.
This will be a fashion store catalog and as such, the products will update very often.

How can I make the application look online for the new products - Obviously I wont push an update to the Play Store every week with hard coded URL's. So how do you guys do it?

P.S
I'm referring to the way to store and get the updates, not the code on how to perform this.
More like, where do you store them?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are getting image URL from web?

Comment: Yes I'm getting them through URL.
Wish I could get them through dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I have created a site at google app engine where you can upload a photo and store it.
there is a need for a service that will accept requests from the android -ex. the android can tell the server that his latest downloaded photo was number 6445, the server can check the DB if a more recent photo is stored,and reply with list of latest photos to download.

on the client side, create a service that will check for new photos every X hours or so.
You can also use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) which is really nice mechanizm! and you could get the update in "real time" and it will save you from pulling which is battery consumer

EDIT 1:
try [Picasa Web Album API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/) - create album, allow the application do download only . allow sync , you're done.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'm looking at both the suggestions you gave. 
To be honest they look pretty complicated for a beginner like me. I was hoping for a simpler solution if possible.